# Converter a sintaxe SQL do banco de dados Firebird banco de dados Postgres para em tempo de execução

Tags: sql, delphi, postgresql, firebird

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi 7 já estável usando o banco de dados do Firebird, e alguns clientes tem solicitado que possam usar o Postgres como banco de dados nesse mesmo sistema.

Como em alguns SELECT'S, o meu sistema utiliza algumas palavras reservadas do Firebird, eu decidi criar um componente intermediário que em tempo de execução, troque estas palavras, ou mude a sintaxe para que o sistema continue a funcionar, tal qual é hoje com Firebird.

Porém, eu gostara de saber se existe algum framework, componente ou mesmo DLL que faça isso. Para que eu não precise reinventar a roda, estudando ambas as sintaxes de cada um e criando verificações para tal. De preferência em Delphi 7 (sendo DLL, pode ser versão superior).

Exemplo:

```sql
--FIREBIRD
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS 
BEGIN 
  IF 
  ( EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM TB_FNC_SEC 
       WHERE FD_FNC = 1
         AND FD_SEC = 'LOC'
         AND FD_KEY = 'FD_FNC'
    ) 
  ) THEN 
    UPDATE TB_FNC_SEC SET 
      FD_VAL = '0'
     WHERE FD_FNC = 1
       AND FD_SEC = 'LOC'
       AND FD_KEY = 'FD_FNC';
  ELSE 
     INSERT INTO TB_FNC_SEC ( 
       FD_FNC,FD_SEC,FD_KEY,FD_VAL 
     ) VALUES ( 
      1,'LOC','FD_FNC','0') ;
END
```

```sql
--POSTGRES
DO
$$ --INICIO
BEGIN 
  IF 
  ( EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM TB_FNC_SEC 
       WHERE FD_FNC = 1
         AND FD_SEC = 'LOC'
         AND FD_KEY = 'FD_FNC'
    ) 
  ) THEN 
    UPDATE TB_FNC_SEC SET 
      FD_VAL = '0'
     WHERE FD_FNC = 1
       AND FD_SEC = 'LOC'
       AND FD_KEY = 'FD_FNC';
  ELSE 
     INSERT INTO TB_FNC_SEC ( 
       FD_FNC, FD_SEC, FD_KEY,FD_VAL 
     ) VALUES ( 
      1, 'LOC','FD_FNC','0') ;

$$
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Na cláusula WHERE do UPDATE do firebird tem `AND FD_SEC = 'LOC'` e no Postgre tem `AND FD_SEC = 'LOCALIZA'`. Essa diferença é intencional? Se sim, porque um é `LOC` e o outro `LOCALIZA`?

Comment: Pressa na digitação. rsrsrs Corrigido para melhor clareza do assunto.

Answer (score 2):

Rapaz complicado essa situação, pois dependendo do tamanho do sistema você terá que fazer muita coisa, sobre um componente terceiro ou DLL nunca ouvi falar sobre!

Então o que podemos fazer?

Abordagem simples e funcional, Adicione `Memos` ou `StringList` com ambos os códigos, e você faz a chamada dependendo dos Clientes em questão.

Declare Variaveis Globais no DataModulo principal de sua aplicação:

```
_PossuiFirebird e _PossuiPostgres
```

Para cada cliente seu em especifico defina as variáveis como `True`.

```
if (_PossuiFirebird = True) then
begin
  ExecSql(MemoFirebird);
end
else if (_PossuiPostgres = True) then
begin
  ExecSql(MemoPostgres)
end;
```

Com esta estrutura você também pode optar por não usar Memos e sim os próprios blocos de códigos usando as variáveis para separar cada caso.

```
if (_PossuiFirebird = True) then
begin
  //Execução de Sql Firebird
  //...
  //Execução de Sql Firebird
end
else if (_PossuiPostgres = True) then
begin
  //Execução de Sql Postgres
  //...
  //Execução de Sql Postgres
end;
```

As vezes chegamos nesse ponto mesmo e vem os desafios, trocar de Banco ou deixar os clientes na mão, e concordamos que ultima opção é inviável!

Hoje tenho uma grande aplicação que usa Firebird, e meu problema é que alguns clientes usam Firebird 2 ou inferior ainda, já outros sempre estão atualizados! Meu maior problema nesse caso foi o **Update or Insert** que é suportado apenas nas versões mais moderas, ao invés de usar 1 único procedimento evitando longos códigos sou obrigado a manter o Update e o Insert separados em 2 blocos de códigos resrsrsrsrs.

Comment: Junior valeu pela dica. Como é o cenário que tenho hoje:

Comment: Junior valeu pela dica. Como é o cenário que tenho hoje: O software ja esta 100% operacional em Firebird, e me foi pedido que fosse convertido os componentes INTERBASE para outro com suporte aos dois Bancos(Firebird/Postgres), isto foi feito e continua 100% operacional no Firebird. A segunda parte é que o sistema funcione da mesma forma no PostGres, desde que eu não altere o sistema, para evitar "tragedias" nos clientes que ja usam no banco atual. E eu desenvolvi um componente que captura o SQL Firebird e transforma em SQL PostGres. Não queria era reinventar a roda caso ja exista.

Answer (score -1):

Estou colocando como resposta pq não tenho reputação suficiente para comentario hehehe porem para a pergunta do victor:

"Na cláusula WHERE do UPDATE do firebird tem AND FD_SEC = 'LOC' e no Postgre tem AND FD_SEC = 'LOCALIZA'. Essa diferença é intencional? Se sim, porque um é LOC e o outro LOCALIZA? – Victor Stafusa 24/11 às 20:13 "

Pressa na digitação não seria a resposta correta, na década de 80 foi criado o padra-o de SQL pela ANSI e pela ISO, uma atitude bem interessante, para evitar que as desenvolvedoras dos SGBD´s não criassem suas próprias linguagens sql como a Oracle estava desenvolvendo, ai surgiram vários padrões porem cada SGBD acaba utilizando um padrão diferente do outro, porem nao ha nada que obrigue eles a usarem o mesmo padrao ou o mais atual.

mas para resolver seu problema a resposta do Junior é a melhor forma !!